# When must a comma be used to separate out results?

Tags: syntax, xquery

Here's the thing...  I have a query:

```
for $item in doc("order.xml")//item 
$name:= doc("catalog.xml")//product[number = $item/@num]/name 
return <item num="{$item/@num" (: a1 :)
    name="{$name}"             (: a2 :)
    quan="{$item/@quantity}"/> (: a3 :)
```

....  No commas, right?  Later, it says "If the comma after `firstresult` were not there, it would be a syntax error because there would be two separate expressions in the query body," about a different query:

```
declare boundary-space preserve;
declare namespace prod = "http://datypic.com/prod";
declare variable $catalog := doc("catalog.xml")//catalog;

<firstResult>{count($catalog/product)}</firstResult>               (: b1 :)
<prod:secondResult>{$catalog/product/number}</prod:secondResult>   (: b2 :)
```

Where is the line drawn between "separate queries" (b1 and b2) and "separate parts of the same query" (a1, a2, and a3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm its just that...

(a1, a2, a3) is a single element node, but spanned on multiple lines  (thats allowed!)

on the other hand (b1, b2) are two separate element nodes,  and to make a sequence ya need to put a comma

Comment: So the line is drawn by node element?  I'll test this.